# installing fos/elasticabundle, it need pagerfanta version

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I want install FOSElasticaBundle, but erorr occured.

I don't know what to do, system cmd shows this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project>composer require friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle
Using version ^5.0 for friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle v5.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle v5.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle v5.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove pagerfanta/pagerfanta v2.0.1
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle ^5.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle[v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install pagerfanta/pagerfanta v2.0.1
    - friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle v5.0.0 requires pagerfanta/pagerfanta ^1.0.5 -> satisfiable by pagerfanta/pagerfanta[v1.0.5, v1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: pagerfanta/pagerfanta[v1.1.0, v2.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: pagerfanta/pagerfanta[v1.0.5, v2.0.1].
    - Installation request for pagerfanta/pagerfanta (locked at v2.0.1) -> satis
fiable by pagerfanta/pagerfanta[v2.0.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

C:\xampp\htdocs\project>
```

I have pagerfanta installed but it works good.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle v5.0.0 requires pagerfanta/pagerfanta ^1.0.5 -> satisfiable by pagerfanta/pagerfanta[v1.0.5, v1.1.0].`

You have pagerfanta/pagerfanta v2.0.1 installed, so to use elastica-bundle v5.0.3 you need to downgrade it to v1.1.0

Comment: what? i really have to do that? is everything work as before after downgrade?

Comment: @user10567054 I don't know. I just answered your questiion. Downgrade and check, or don't use friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle v5.0.3.

Comment: thanks for help, i downgraded, and it downloading elastics now.